# what if i do not set error message in required field validator?

Tags: asp.net, .net, requiredfieldvalidator

If i do not set error message in required field validator, will it display msg pop up box or not? my code-

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" 
  ValidationGroup="Search" ID="RFV_ddlTimeSlot" Display="None" 
  ControlToValidate="ddlTimeSlot" InitialValue="--Select Time Slot--"
  ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Since you have code, why not spend a min, and post your observation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will still validate.  Why not spend 5 mins trying it out?

Answer (score 1):

So it will still validate the control but will not show any message.

Answer (score 1):

Whenver your control have invalid values and validation occurs your RequiredFieldValidator will show a *****.